# Refreshing a jtable to reflect a change made to the database-JAVA MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql

How do you reload  a jtable after carrying out a delete or insert on DB

Answer (score 0):

Well, the safest way is probably to re-execute the DB query used to get the table data, then rebuild a table model, and call setModel on your JTable (or pass the new data to a custom `setData()` method of  your `TableModel` implementation, and call `fireTableDataChanged()` from this `setData()` method).

Comment: Whoa!! Ok...im using beans binding so once i get the selected object i delete it ...So how do i run this method..i have come across it but i dnt know how to use it.